# How can I create a vector of a color in r?

Tags: r

I imported an image like this:

```
importedImage <- readPNG(fileName)
```

then I turned it into a dataframe:

```
originalImage <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:dimensions[2], each = dimensions[1]),
  y = rep(dimensions[1]:1),
  value = as.vector(importedImage))
```

alright, so I plotted with gray like this:

```
image_ggplot <- ggplot(originalImage, aes(x = x, y = y))
image_ggplot <- image_ggplot + geom_point(colour = gray(originalImage$value))
image_ggplot <- image_ggplot + labs(title = as.character(fileName))
image_ggplot <- image_ggplot + xlab("x") + scale_size("identity")
image_ggplot <- image_ggplot + ylab("y")
```

But since I'm dealing with clusters I created a palette of colors, which I'd like to plot one over the other. How can I create a vector such as I did with gray()? I tried plotting but the other colors block out the image base.

Comment: what does `dimensions` object contains ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by plotting the palette one over the other? Can you upload the example image?